# Fastify Depreciation: request.connection property

Tags: node.js, discord, fastify

my problem is related to my discord bot dashboard, the login system exactly.

First: I tried to login in the site, once i click "authorize", the site return a error: Failed to obtain access token", i going check my server console, and it said: "FastifyDeprecation: You are accessing the deprecated "request.connection" property. Use "request.socket" instead."

Second: I browse my code, I used ctrl+f and i didn't find .connection or .socket

Here is my code:

````js
// index.js
const http = require('http')

let server

const serverFactory = (handler, opts) => {
  server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    handler(req, res)
  })

  return server
};
require("./strategies/discordstrategy");
const fastify = require("fastify")({ serverFactory });
const session = require("@fastify/session");
const passport = require("@fastify/passport");

const path = require("path");

require("./database/database");

fastify.register(require("@fastify/static"), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "assets"),
  prefix: '/assets/',
  decorateReply: false 
});


fastify.register(require("@fastify/formbody"));

fastify.register(require("@fastify/view"), {
  engine: {
    ejs: require("ejs"),
  },
});

fastify.register(require("@fastify/cookie"));
fastify.register(session, {
  cookieName: "discord.oauth",
  secret: "Un secret avec minimum 32 lettres ou nombres!",
  cookie: { secure: false },
  saveUninitialized: false,
  maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24,
});

fastify.register(passport.initialize());
fastify.register(passport.secureSession());
fastify.register(require("./routes/auth"), { prefix: "/auth" });
fastify.register(require("./routes/dashboard"), { prefix: "/dashboard" });

fastify.get("/", { preValidation: isAuthorized }, (req, rep) => {
  rep.view("/pages/index.ejs", {
    users: false,
  });
});

function isAuthorized(req, rep, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    console.log("Utilisateur autorisé!");
    rep.redirect("/dashboard");
  } else {
    console.log("Utilisateur non autorisé!");
    next();
  }
}
fastify.ready(() => {
  server.listen({ port: 8080 })
})


// routes/auth.js
const passport = require("@fastify/passport");

module.exports = function (fastify, opts, done) {
  fastify.get(
    "/",
    { preValidation: passport.authenticate("discord") },
    async (req, rep) => {}
  );

  fastify.get(
    "/redirect",
    {
      preValidation: passport.authenticate("discord", {
        failureRedirect: "/forbidden",
        successRedirect: "/dashboard",
      }),
    },
    async (req, rep) => {}
  );

  fastify.get("/logout", async (req, rep) => {
    if(req.user) {
      req.logout();
      rep.redirect("/");
    } else {
      rep.redirect("/");
    }
  })

  function isAuthorized(req, rep, next) {
    if (req.user) {
      console.log("User is authorized");
      console.log(req.user);
      next();
    } else {
      console.log("User is not authorized");
      rep.redirect("/");
    }
  }

  done();
};


// routes/dashboard.js
module.exports = function (fastify, opts, done) {
  function isAuthorized(req, rep, next) {
    if (req.user) {
      console.log("User is authorized");
      console.log(req.user);
      next();
    } else {
      console.log("User is not authorized");
      rep.redirect("/");
    }
  }

  fastify.get(
    "/",
    {
      preValidation: isAuthorized,
    },
    async (req, rep) => {
      rep.view("/pages/dashboard.ejs", {
        user: req.user.username,
        discordId: req.user.discordId,
        guilds: req.user.guilds,
      });
    }
  );

  fastify.get(
    "/settings",
    {
      preValidation: isAuthorized,
    },
    async (req, rep) => {
      rep.code(200).send("OK");
    }
  );

  done();
};```

I don't have a script about the login system in my dashboard page, so i don't know where is the problem.
````